# No me detecta la función creada JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estoy intentando obtener los datos de un formulario e imprimirlos en pantalla, pero no, al ingresarle una función anónima no me realiza el `console.log`, ¿qué puedo hacer?, es un problema que he tenido en algunos proyectos.

Muchas gracias

```js
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");

  formulario.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    console.log("Evento submit capturado");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Ejercicios</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Ejercicio DOM y eventos</h1>
  <p>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="formulario">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
      <br>

      <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="apellidos">
      <br>

      <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="edad">
      <br>

      <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="submit">
    </form>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El código funciona perfectamente. En el evento `submit` se está imprimiendo por consola "Evento submit capturado". Puedes poner un `event.preventDefault();` antes del `console.log` (pasándole `event` como parámetro a tu función anónima) y verás que llega al submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ayuda a futuras veces que te ocurra este problema (ya que te lo han resuelto bien ya)
1º) Mirar en la consola del navegador que no te da fallo al leer el app.js, puede parecer una tontería, pero a veces, si escribes el nombre del archivo a mano, puede colarse alguna typo y causar un 404, entiendo que ahora no es el problema.
2º) Si te pasa el punto 1, actuar un un debugger. El debugger es el salvador de los informáticos.

Espero que te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, puedes cancelar el evento de submit por default del formulario, eso se hace con con `preventDefault()`

Hazlo de esta manera:

```js
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");

  formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Evento submit capturado");
    // Todo tu codigo va acá
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Ejercicios</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Ejercicio DOM y eventos</h1>
  <p>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="formulario">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
      <br>

      <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="apellidos">
      <br>

      <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="edad">
      <br>

      <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="submit">
    </form>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```